# reading .csv file with read_csv() results in only one column

Tags: r, read.csv

> Groenigen, Kees Jan van, Xuan Qi, Craig W. Osenberg, Yiqi Luo, and
> Bruce A. Hungate. “Faster Decomposition Under Increased Atmospheric
> CO2 Limits Soil Carbon Storage.” Science 344, no. 6183 (May 2, 2014):
> 508–9. https://doi.org/10.1126/science.1249534.

I have this .xlxs file from a paper and have to tidy it and read it into R. When I try to do that all the columns are put into one column, and the values are seperated by a semicolon.

It looks like this "ArizonaFACE - wheat - high N;0;1344;1228;4;4", instead of it being it 6 columns. What do i do wrong? I use the read_csv()

As said above, what i already tried

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are trying to read a .xlsx file with a read_csv() function.
There are many packages which allow to easily import .xlsx files.
Just as an example

```
df <- readxl::read_excel("path")
```

If you do actually have a .csv file as mentioned in the title, then the separator in your file is propably different than the default in the function. You can open the data in a simple text editor to see the separator.